# How to recover a deleted DFS namespace

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, restore, dfs

I deleted a DFS namespace to rebuild it in a different way, but it turns out there was a linked folder underneath that namespace that pointed to a share somewhere. Nobody knows where the share of the sub folder is located. The namespace server is not backupped. Is there any way to retrieve this information from a restored DC (I use VEEAM, so restoring the entire DC is relatively easy) through ADUC or ADSI Edit and if so, how should I go about?
Thanks!

Comment: Recreating that DFS namespace should bring it back. Not entirely sure, but about 80%... On second thought, if that doesn't work, then it probably worked for me because at that time I was migrating from one DC to another, and actually had 2 DC's in the forest.

Comment: I tried recreating the namespace, but the subfolder did not appear. 
In the meantime a backup of the data IN the subfolder has been found, so I was able to make the necessary data available to end-users again.

Answer (score 0):

As the data IN the DFS folder has been restored from a backup set I am no longer looking for an answer to my initial question.